# Unable to inspect picker elements of react-native-picker v1.7.2 component in Appium inspector for both Android and IOS

Tags: react-native, datepicker, appium, appium-inspector

I work on test automation . I am trying to select an expiry date in the date picker component . App is implemented using react native. Developer has used date picker component available in https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker . But I am unable to see the android tags corresponding to the date picker in Appium inspector and UIAutomatorViewer. The app source looks like below
[inspector app source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLiUH.png)

After the last android.view.ViewGroup tag , nothing is displayed for date picker in inspector.

As a workaround , we asked the developer to set ids for ‘Cancel’ and ‘Confirm’ buttons . So that atleast we can select first date and proceed . But the developer informed that the date picker is coming from reactive-native-picker library(1.7.2 version) . So they are unable to set any ids inside for the ‘Cancel’ and ‘Confirm’ buttons.

Please find the xml source which copied from inspector . There is no mention of the date picker element
[xml source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yxhx.jpg)

Any help is appreciated . Thanks in advance.